# sarhan custom font space problem

Tags: iphone, custom-font

I am using sarhan custom font . But the space character is not reflecting in to the text. It's just replacing to next character in place of space. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Never heard of such font (google also has not given me any results). Nevertheless, you should contact the font maker/s as they seem to have messed things up.

Comment: actually font is working fine for all other character. Only problem is with space. when ever i enter space , it just replacing next character. any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i resolved the problem . we have to modify the .ttf file of font and replacing the correct value for character.